# Stacked bar chart scale inconsistency issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following D3 code (working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ksa01/ufxyt3q7/)) using the latest D3 release and I'm trying to build a simple stacked bar chart.

```
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const padding = 30
const margins = {
  left: 60,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 50,
  top: 15
}
const svgDimensions = {
  height: 434,
  width: 734
}
const chartPerimeterDimensions = {
  width: svgDimensions.width - margins.left - margins.right,
  height: svgDimensions.height - margins.top - margins.bottom
}

const barChartData = [
  { age: 55, patient: 0.1, population: 0 },
  { age: 56, patient: 0.2, population: 0.1 },
  { age: 57, patient: 0.3, population: 0.1 },
  { age: 58, patient: 0.5, population: 0.2 },
  { age: 59, patient: 0.6, population: 0.3 },
  { age: 60, patient: 0.8, population: 0.4 },
  { age: 61, patient: 1, population: 0.5 },
  { age: 62, patient: 1.2, population: 0.6 },
  { age: 63, patient: 1.5, population: 0.7 },
  { age: 64, patient: 1.8, population: 0.8 },
  { age: 65, patient: 2.2, population: 1 },
  { age: 66, patient: 2.6, population: 1.2 },
  { age: 67, patient: 3.1, population: 1.4 },
  { age: 68, patient: 3.7, population: 1.7 },
  { age: 69, patient: 4.3, population: 2 },
  { age: 70, patient: 5, population: 2.4 },
  { age: 71, patient: 5.8, population: 2.8 },
  { age: 72, patient: 6.8, population: 3.2 },
  { age: 73, patient: 7.9, population: 3.7 },
  { age: 74, patient: 9.1, population: 4.4 },
  { age: 75, patient: 10.5, population: 5 },
  { age: 76, patient: 12.1, population: 5.9 },
  { age: 77, patient: 13.9, population: 6.8 },
  { age: 78, patient: 15.9, population: 7.9 },
  { age: 79, patient: 18.2, population: 9.2 },
  { age: 80, patient: 20.7, population: 10.6 },
  { age: 81, patient: 23.5, population: 12.2 },
  { age: 82, patient: 30.1, population: 14.2 },
  { age: 83, patient: 33.4, population: 16.4 },
  { age: 84, patient: 36.7, population: 18.9 },
  { age: 85, patient: 38, population: 21.8 } ]

const yMax = Math.max(barChartData[30].patient, barChartData[30].population)
const yMin = 0
const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([yMin, yMax + 10])
    .range([chartPerimeterDimensions.height, 0])

  // Establish x scale
const xSeries = barChartData.map(d => d.age);
const xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .range([0, chartPerimeterDimensions.width])
    .padding(0.1);

xScale
    .domain(xSeries)
    .paddingOuter(padding / xScale.step());

const keys = ["population", "patient"]
const colors = ["grey", "red"]
const colorScale = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(keys)
    .range(colors)

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues([55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85])
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)

  // Create the group to place our chart within
const chartGroup = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${margins.top})`)

  // Create D3 stack data
const values = d3
    .stack()
    .keys(keys)(barChartData)

  // Add stacked bar chart to svg
chartGroup
    .selectAll("g.bars")
    .data(values)
    .join("g")
      .attr("fill", d => colorScale(d.key))
      .attr('class', 'bars')
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(d => {
      return d
    })
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => xScale(d.data.age))
      .attr("y", d => {
        const result = yScale(d[1])
        return result
      })
      .attr("height", d => {
        const result = yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1])
        return result
      })
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr('class', 'bar')

  /**
   * Create Y-Axis
   */
svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${margins.top})`)
    .call(yAxis)

  /**
   * Create X-Axis
   */
svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${svgDimensions.height - margins.bottom})`)
    .call(xAxis)
```

I realize the bars for the population are perfect however the patient bars are quite long and overflowing into the top of the chart despite the max value in this dataset being 38. I'm wondering if it's an issue with:

- a misconfigured y-scale function
- misconfigured stack data

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I've realized the I may be using the wrong type of chart for this dataset. A grouped bar chart would probably have been a better choice since I'm trying to show discrete, numerical comparisons amongst categories (ie, age).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **stacked** bar chart. Therefore, getting the maximum of the two variables...

```
const yMax = Math.max(barChartData[30].patient, barChartData[30].population)
```

... is not the correct way to set the upper domain. On top of that, you should not trust that the last object has the maximum value.

That being said, you can get the maximum using the stacked data itself:

```
const yMax = d3.max(values[values.length - 1], function(d){
    return d[1];
});
```

Here is the resulting code:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const padding = 30
const margins = {
  left: 60,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 50,
  top: 15
}
const svgDimensions = {
  height: 434,
  width: 734
}
const chartPerimeterDimensions = {
  width: svgDimensions.width - margins.left - margins.right,
  height: svgDimensions.height - margins.top - margins.bottom
}

const barChartData = [{
    age: 55,
    patient: 0.1,
    population: 0
  },
  {
    age: 56,
    patient: 0.2,
    population: 0.1
  },
  {
    age: 57,
    patient: 0.3,
    population: 0.1
  },
  {
    age: 58,
    patient: 0.5,
    population: 0.2
  },
  {
    age: 59,
    patient: 0.6,
    population: 0.3
  },
  {
    age: 60,
    patient: 0.8,
    population: 0.4
  },
  {
    age: 61,
    patient: 1,
    population: 0.5
  },
  {
    age: 62,
    patient: 1.2,
    population: 0.6
  },
  {
    age: 63,
    patient: 1.5,
    population: 0.7
  },
  {
    age: 64,
    patient: 1.8,
    population: 0.8
  },
  {
    age: 65,
    patient: 2.2,
    population: 1
  },
  {
    age: 66,
    patient: 2.6,
    population: 1.2
  },
  {
    age: 67,
    patient: 3.1,
    population: 1.4
  },
  {
    age: 68,
    patient: 3.7,
    population: 1.7
  },
  {
    age: 69,
    patient: 4.3,
    population: 2
  },
  {
    age: 70,
    patient: 5,
    population: 2.4
  },
  {
    age: 71,
    patient: 5.8,
    population: 2.8
  },
  {
    age: 72,
    patient: 6.8,
    population: 3.2
  },
  {
    age: 73,
    patient: 7.9,
    population: 3.7
  },
  {
    age: 74,
    patient: 9.1,
    population: 4.4
  },
  {
    age: 75,
    patient: 10.5,
    population: 5
  },
  {
    age: 76,
    patient: 12.1,
    population: 5.9
  },
  {
    age: 77,
    patient: 13.9,
    population: 6.8
  },
  {
    age: 78,
    patient: 15.9,
    population: 7.9
  },
  {
    age: 79,
    patient: 18.2,
    population: 9.2
  },
  {
    age: 80,
    patient: 20.7,
    population: 10.6
  },
  {
    age: 81,
    patient: 23.5,
    population: 12.2
  },
  {
    age: 82,
    patient: 30.1,
    population: 14.2
  },
  {
    age: 83,
    patient: 33.4,
    population: 16.4
  },
  {
    age: 84,
    patient: 36.7,
    population: 18.9
  },
  {
    age: 85,
    patient: 38,
    population: 21.8
  }
]

const yMin = 0


// Establish x scale
const xSeries = barChartData.map(d => d.age);
const xScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .range([0, chartPerimeterDimensions.width])
  .padding(0.1);

xScale
  .domain(xSeries)
  .paddingOuter(padding / xScale.step());

const keys = ["population", "patient"]
const colors = ["grey", "red"]
const colorScale = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(keys)
  .range(colors)

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues([55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85])


// Create the group to place our chart within
const chartGroup = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${margins.top})`)

// Create D3 stack data
const values = d3
  .stack()
  .keys(keys)(barChartData);

const yMax = d3.max(values[values.length - 1], function(d) {
  return d[1];
});

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([yMin, yMax + 10])
  .range([chartPerimeterDimensions.height, 0])

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)

// Add stacked bar chart to svg
chartGroup
  .selectAll("g.bars")
  .data(values)
  .join("g")
  .attr("fill", d => colorScale(d.key))
  .attr('class', 'bars')
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => {
    return d
  })
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", d => xScale(d.data.age))
  .attr("y", d => {
    const result = yScale(d[1])
    return result
  })
  .attr("height", d => {
    const result = yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1])
    return result
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('class', 'bar')

/**
 * Create Y-Axis
 */
svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${margins.top})`)
  .call(yAxis)

/**
 * Create X-Axis
 */
svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${svgDimensions.height - margins.bottom})`)
  .call(xAxis)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="434" width="734"></svg>
```

Comment: In my case I always know the last values in the data set are the max values because they're ascending. I've realized the I may be using the wrong type of chart for this dataset. A grouped bar chart would probably have been a better choice since I'm trying to show discrete, numerical comparisons amongst categories (ie, age). I'll accept your answer

Comment: maybe I understand it wrong, but aren't the values in the stack "positions", for setting where they get drawn, not actual min max values?  In this case, the max value would be the max coordinate, not the max value?